# Is the NuGet Package Manager returning an error?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I reinstall manually NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015. Now when I open Package Manager Console I see such information:

> NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

If that is indicate problem what need to do to fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nuget is simply a tool to install packages (such as libraries).  The message simply says they are not responsible for what you could install.

Also, some packages depend on other packages to work properly. So, trying to install 1 package may result in installing 3.

Finally, it is your responsibility to check the license that comes with the packages you install.  The license is the contract that says what you can do and can't do with a package. For instance, can you use the package in a commercial project ? Can you resell the package ? Etc.

What you see is **NOT** an error.  It is a simple warning.